# How to create a custom validator to reject a time duration < 10 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, time

I have a cardio exercise model with a "duration" field of the time datatype (Rails 4.2.6 / Ruby 2.2.4 application). I need help troubleshooting a custom validator to prevent users from saving an aerobic workout which is less than 10 minutes in duration.

Here's the relevant field in my _form.html.erb:

```
<%= f.input :duration do %> <br>
<%= f.time_select :duration, :include_blank => true, include_seconds: true %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my custom validator in /app/validators/duration_exceeds_ten_min_validator.rb

```
class DurationExceedsTenMinValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
          unless duration_exceeds_ten_min
          record.errors[attribute] << "must be at least 10 min"
        end
     end

  private

# Check if duration is greater than or equal to 10 minutes, a.k.a. duration_exceeds_ten_min
# If that's the case, return true, otherwise false.

  def duration_exceeds_ten_min
    if Time.parse(self.duration.strftime("%H:%M:%S") < "00:10:00")
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

In my cardio_exercise model (cardio_exercise.rb), I added this:

```
validates :duration, duration_exceeds_ten_min: true
```

When the code executes, it throws the following error:

```
 undefined method `duration' for #<DurationExceedsTenMinValidator:0x0000000ef5c4c8>
```

When I "force" a true or false condition, the custom validator appears to work properly.  There is something wrong with my if statement. I'm stuck; I can't figure out how to set up the condition properly.  How do I fix my custom validator?  I appreciate any help & advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my custom validator was caused by my failure to include the option to "ignore_date" in the time_select HTML.

While reviewing my source code, I noticed date values were included with a user's inputted time values. The custom validator failed because of these "hidden fields." Ruby on Rails documentation states: "This method [time_select] will also generate 3 input hidden tags, for the actual year, month and day unless the option :ignore_date is set to true."

My custom validator works as expected after I set the option ":ignore_date to true" in my HTML. That change in the HTML solved the problem.  Users can no longer save cardio exercises less than 10 minutes in duration.  I hope this is useful information to someone else in the future.

I give credit to @max for helping me improve my custom validator, and for explaining why the placement of "self" in the validator would not work versus in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the time to seconds and let ActiveSupport::Duration do the hard work.

```
 def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
   if value.to_i.seconds < 10.minutes
     record.errors[attribute] << "must be at least 10 min"
   end
 end
```

If you are interested in why your method does not work it because you are using `self.duration` in your validator. `self` in this context is the validator - not the model.

Comment: Tried suggested solution, but can't get it to work: now the validator is prevents saving whether duration is < or > 10 minutes. Can you update your answer in the context of my code?  I may be missing something about your suggested solution.

Comment: Are you sure that the duration is not nil? That could be the case if you for example are not whitelisting the parameter.

Comment: Because `nil.to_i.seconds == 0.seconds`

Comment: "duration" is a permitted parameter. It's not nil. I'm testing it with a value like 00:05:00 and 00:10:01

Comment: Ah, could it be that the value of duration is a string (`"00:05:00"`) and not a Time or DateTime?

Comment: That would explain it since `"00:05:00".to_i == 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124251/discussion-between-max-and-codeinspired).